# Prove that an Eigen value of anti-symmetric matrix is either zero or

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to prove the following:

1. Prove that an eigenvalue of anti-symmetric matrix is either zero or imaginary.
2. Prove that the eigenvectors of a symmetric tensor are orthogonal.

Comment: As $A^T=-A$, we conclude $(iA)^*=iA$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is partly based on [Hagen von Eitzen's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291337/prove-that-an-eigen-value-of-anti-symmetric-matrix-is-either-zero-or#comment634735_291337).

---

Since $A^T = -A$, $(iA)^* = iA$; that is, $iA$ is self-adjoint, hence has real eigenvalues; it follows that $A$ has imaginary eigenvalues.

To prove the second point, you can generalize the approach for matrices given by [Arturo Magidin here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/82471/43351).