# Do Real Symmetric Matrices have 'n' linearly independent eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I know that Real Symmetric Matrices have real eigenvalues and the vectors corresponding to each distinct eigenvalue is orthogonal from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/82471/516816). But what if the matrix has repeated eigenvalues? Does it have linearly independent (and orthogonal) eigenvectors? How to prove that?

PS: In the answer I referred to has another answer which might have answered this question. I'm not sure if it answered my question since I didn't understand it. If it did answer my question, can anyone please explain it?

Thanks!

Comment: For each eigenvalue $\lambda$, you can use gram-schmidt process to find an orthonormal basis for the eigenspaces with respect to $\lambda$.

Comment: In general for a square matrix, if there are repeated eigenvalues, there may not be n distinct eigenvectors right? Is it true for Symmetric Matrices as well or do symmetric matrices have distinct eigenvectors even with repeated eigenvalues?

Comment: Basically you are asking why a real symmetric matrix is diagonalizable. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/82472/99914) addressed this, but some details are skipped.

Comment: What you are seeking is the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Hermitian_maps_and_Hermitian_matrices)

Comment: @JohnMa, yes. But I didn't understand how he proves. He just says from induction and proceeds. Can you explain that part please?

Comment: @Bungo, I have heard the term Spectral Theorem. I read the wikipedia page. I didn't quite get it. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eigenvectors of real symmetric matrices are orthogonal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82467/eigenvectors-of-real-symmetric-matrices-are-orthogonal)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Real Symmetric Matrices have $n$ linearly independent and orthogonal eigenvectors.

There are two parts here. 
1. The eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal which is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/82471/516816). 
2. If some of the eigenvalues are repeated, since the matrix is Real Symmetric, there will exist so many independent eigenvectors. (Proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1517545/516816) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1844686/516816).) As [John Ma](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/99914/john-ma) pointed out, in this case we can use *Gram–Schmidt* orthogonalization to get orthogonal vectors.

So, all $n$ eigenvectors of a Real Symmetric matrix are linearly independent and orthogonal