# Bounded singular value of a positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, singular-values

Consider the symmetric positive definite matrix ${M}$ such that its inverse ${M}^{-1}$ has also diagonal entries 1 and non-diagonal entries, each bounded by a constant $c' < 1$. Now, can we bound the value $x\cdot{M}^{\top}{M}\cdot x$ where $x \in \{-1,1\}^n$.

Apparently, we are trying to understand the largest singular values of ${M}$ here such that $\|{M}x\|_2$ is maximized. We know that it would correspond to the eigenvector of $({M}^{\top}{M})$. Can we say that bound has the form $\|{M}x\|_2 < c\cdot n$ where $c$ is a fixed number?

Comment: it would be nice to know what *"non-diagonal entries bounded by a constant $c' < 1$"* means.  I doubt the literal reading of this is correct and suspect you are instead referring to the modulus of these entries.  Also the constraints on $\mathbf x$ seem to potentially clash with the interest in singular values.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, for every real symmetric matrix $M$, the normalized eigenvectors $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n$ of $M$ span the whole space (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482599/why-are-real-symmetric-matrices-diagonalizable) for proof). Without loss of generality, we assume such vectors are jointly orthogonal as well.

This means that one can rewrite each vector $x$ as
\begin{equation}
x = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i v_i.
\end{equation}

As a result, we have
\begin{equation}
Mx = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \lambda_i v_i,
\end{equation}
where concludes
\begin{equation}
\|Mx\|_2 =  \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^2c_i^2},
\end{equation}
since $\|v_i\|_2=1$, and due to orthogonality of $v_i$s, where $\lambda_i$s are eigenvalues of $M$.

Further, since $x\in \{-1, 1\}^n$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i^2= n$. As a result, we have
\begin{equation}
\|Mx\|_2 \leq \sqrt{n}|\lambda_{\max}|,
\end{equation}
where $\lambda_{\max}$ is the eigenvalue with maximum absolute value.

Finally, Greshorin's circle theorem (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem)), expresses that the eigenvalues of a matrix $M$ lies one circles with $M$s diagonal elements as centers and absolute sum of non-diagonal elements as radius's. Hence, for this matrix, we have $|\lambda_{\max}|< n$.

Finally, using above discussions we have
\begin{equation}
\|Mx\|_2 < n\sqrt{n}.
\end{equation}

My conjecture is that, the rate $O(n\sqrt{n})$ is optimal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe I'm missing something but it is not very clear how you arrived at the bound on $|\lambda_{\max}|$. Can you estimate the entries of $M$ from $M^{-1}$?