# Prove that if $A$ is normal, then eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are necessarily orthogonal (alternative proof)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, alternative-proof

The problem statement is as follows:

> Prove that for a normal matrix $A$, eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are necessarily orthogonal.

I can certainly prove that this is the case, using the spectral theorem.  The gist of my proof is presented below.

If possible, I would like to find a simpler proof.  I was hoping that there might be some sort of manipulation [along these lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/82471/81360), noting that
$$
\langle Av_1,A v_2\rangle 
= \langle v_1,A^*Av_2\rangle 
= \langle v_1,AA^*v_2\rangle 
= \langle A^* v_1,A^* v_2 \rangle
$$

Any ideas here would be appreciated.

---

### My proof:

Let $\{v_{\lambda,i}\}$ be an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors (as guaranteed by the spectral theorem) such that
$$
A v_{\lambda,i} = \lambda v_{\lambda,i}
$$
Let $v_1,\lambda_1$ and $v_2,\lambda_2$ be eigenpairs with $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$.  We may write
$
v_1 = \sum_{i,\lambda}a_{i,\lambda}v_{i,\lambda}
.$
We then have
$$
0 = Av_1 - \lambda_1 v_1 = \sum_{i,\lambda}(\lambda - \lambda_1)a_{i,\lambda}v_{i,\lambda}
$$
So that $a_{i,\lambda} = 0$ when $\lambda \neq \lambda_1$.  Similarly, we may write $v_2 = \sum_{i,\lambda}b_{i,\lambda}v_{i,\lambda}$, and note that $b_{i,\lambda} = 0$ when $\lambda \neq \lambda_2$.  From there, we have
$$
\langle v_1,v_2 \rangle = \sum_{i,\lambda}a_{i,\lambda}b_{i,\lambda}
$$
the above must be zero since for each pair $i,\lambda$, either $a_{i,\lambda}=0$ or $b_{i,\lambda} = 0$.

Comment: "Let $v_{\lambda,i}$ be an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors..." I'd guess that this might be something very close to what would need to be proved.

Comment: @PavelJiranek I was worried that I had used circular logic at some point.  However, the existence of such a basis (i.e. the spectral theorem) comes directly from the Schur triangularization theorem, which says nothing about normal matrices in particular.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assume $\;\lambda\neq \mu\;$ and

$$\begin{cases}Av=\lambda v\;\,\implies\; A^*v=\overline \lambda v\\{}\\Aw=\mu w\implies A^*w=\overline\mu w\end{cases}$$

From this we get:

$$\begin{cases}\langle v,Aw\rangle=\langle v,\mu w\rangle=\overline\mu\langle v,w\rangle\\{}\\
\langle v,Aw\rangle=\langle A^*v,w\rangle=\langle\overline\lambda v,w\rangle=\overline\lambda\langle v,w\rangle \end{cases}$$

and since $\;\overline\mu\neq\overline\lambda\;$ , we get $\;\langle v,w\rangle =0\;$

**Question:** Where did we use normality in the above?

Comment: How de we know that $v$ is also an eigenvector for $A^*$?

Comment: @Berci, read and think of the question at the end of the answer.

Comment: From the other two answers this follows, of course, using that $A$ is normal. But can you show it directly?

Comment: Why directly? Use the definition and work it out. I *usually* don't give full answers and, after all, the OP is trying to get a more or less simpler proof to the claim than the one using the spectral theorem...

Comment: I like it!  Showing that $Av=\lambda v\;\,\implies\; A^*v=\overline \lambda v$ seems to be the step in the spirit of what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: A pleasure, @Omnomnomnom .

Comment: Can someone give me a clue as to where you used normality in the above?

Comment: @ikoikoia The very first $\;\implies\;$ is false in general if $\;A\;$ isn't normal.

Comment: Because it has basis  consisting of eigenvectors

Comment: If p(x,y) is a polynomial then since A is normal, the matrix B := p(A,A*) is also normal. Normality of B implies that B and B* have the same kernel, using the identity <Bv,Bv> = <B* v,B* v> derived by the OP. By taking p(x,y) := x-lambda we get the implications asserted in the answer above.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3015399/516816)

Answer (score 13):

Specializing your identity to $v_1=v_2=v$, we get $\|Av\|=\|A^*v\|$. Hence $\ker A=\ker A^*$. Recalling that $\ker A^* = (\operatorname{ran} A)^\perp$ for general $A$, we conclude that the kernel and range of a normal matrix are mutually orthogonal.

It remains to apply the above conclusion to $A-\lambda I$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: Neat!  Although DonAntonio's proof is more along the lines I was thinking of, this is a nice perspective.

Answer (score 10):

The answers to this question are very good but they are glossing over the fact that if $A \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$ is normal then $Ax = \lambda x \implies A^*x = \bar \lambda x$. I think it's helpful to just spell out the whole thing explicitly.

**Lemma:** If $M \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$ is normal, then $M$ and $M^*$ have the same null space.

**Proof:** Let $M \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$ be a normal matrix. Then
\begin{align}
&M^*x = 0 \\
\iff & \| M^* x \|^2 = 0 \\
\iff & \langle M^*x, M^* x \rangle = 0 \\
\iff & \langle M M^* x, x \rangle = 0 \\
\iff & \langle M^* M x, x \rangle = 0 \\
\iff & \langle Mx, Mx \rangle = 0 \\
\iff & \| Mx \|^2 = 0 \\
\iff & Mx = 0.
\end{align}

**Lemma:** If $A \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$ is normal then $Ax = \lambda x \implies A^* x = \bar \lambda x$.

**Proof:** Suppose that $A \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$ is normal and $Ax = \lambda x$. So $x$ is a null vector of $M = A - \lambda I$.
Note that $M$ is normal, as you can check by expanding both $M^* M$ and $M M^*$.
By the above lemma, $x$ is also a null vector of $M^* = A^* - \bar \lambda I$. Thus $A^*x = \bar \lambda x$.

**Theorem:** If $x$ and $y$ are eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues of a normal matrix $A \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$, then $\langle x, y \rangle = 0$.

**Proof:**
Let $A \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$ be a normal matrix, and suppose that $x$ and $y$ are eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to distinct eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $\gamma$, respectively.
Note that
$$\langle x, Ay \rangle = \langle x, \gamma y \rangle = \bar \gamma \langle x, y \rangle.$$
On the other hand,
$$
\langle x, Ay \rangle = \langle A^* x, y \rangle = \langle \bar \lambda x, y \rangle = \bar \lambda \langle x, y \rangle.
$$
So we find that $\bar \gamma \langle x, y \rangle = \bar \lambda \langle x, y \rangle$, which implies that $\langle x, y \rangle = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer!
Shouldn't the last member of the last two displayed expressions have unconjugated gamma and lambda?

Comment: @RodolfoOviedo I’m using the convention that if $x, y \in \mathbb C^n$ then $\langle x, y \rangle = \sum_i x_i \bar{y_i}$. With this convention, I think the way that I wrote it is correct. Sometimes people (especially physicists, I believe) define $\langle x, y \rangle$ to be $\sum_i \bar{x_i} y_i$. Perhaps you have that definition in mind.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
After the second sentence of the proof of the second lemma, I would add: Because $A$ is normal, so is $M$, as you can check by expanding both $M^*M$ and $MM^*$.

Comment: Am I right? If so, should you or I edit the answer?

Comment: @RodolfoOviedo I just made the change you suggested, thanks.

Comment: You might want to answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4441708/how-to-prove-if-a-and-b-are-normal-matrices-and-ab-ba-ab-and-ab-are
I was tempted to invoke point 1 of this proposition, which I found in Wikipedia, but... I could not prove it.

Answer (score 3):

I try to give another simple proof to $$T^*v=\bar{\lambda}v  ~\text{  if  }~  Tv=\lambda v$$ where $T$ is a normal operator on a Hilbert space $H$.

Suppose $V=\ker(T-\lambda I)$. Since $T^*$ communicate with $T$, $$T^*V\subset V.$$
Because 
$$\langle v,T^*v\rangle =\langle Tv,v\rangle =\langle \lambda v,v\rangle=\langle v,\bar{\lambda}v\rangle ~~\forall v \in V, $$
$\langle u,T^*v\rangle =\langle u, \bar{\lambda}v\rangle ~\forall u,v\in V$ by polarisation identity,  and thus $T^*v=\bar{\lambda}v.$

REMARK: Let $\sigma:V\times V\to W$ be a sesquilinear form, where $V$ and $W$ are linear vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$. The follwing formula is called  **Polarisation Identity** :
$$\sigma(u,v)=\sum_{k=0}^3 i^k\sigma(u+i^k v, u+i^kv). $$

Comment: I don't really see how this answer addresses the question being asked.  Also, the question being asked was answered 3 years ago.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom This is  why $Av=\lambda v\Rightarrow A^*v=\bar{\lambda}v$ using no spectral theorem which is the point to the question I think.

Comment: That is not the point to the question, actually. The point is to show that eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are necessarily orthogonal.

Comment: Oh, sorry to disturb you. As I give some additional remarks to the right answer you have accepted.

Answer (score 3):

[linear_algebra_done_right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb5XL.png)
This is from *linear algebra done right*. btw, it's the greatest book about linear algebra I've ever seen!

---

*Proof:* Suppose $\alpha,\beta$ are distinct eigenvalues of $T$, with corresponding eigenvectors $u,v$. Thus, $Tu = \alpha u$ and $Tv = \beta v$. From 7.21 we have $T^*v = \bar \beta v.$ Thus,
\begin{align}
(\alpha - \beta)\langle u,v \rangle &= \langle \alpha u,v \rangle  - \langle u, \bar \beta v \rangle 
\\ &= 
\langle Tu,v \rangle - \langle u, T^*v \rangle
\\ & = 0.
\end{align}
Because $\alpha \neq \beta$, the equation above implies $\langle u,v \rangle = 0$. Thus, $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal, as desired.

Comment: LADR should have been the first place that I looked. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the notation from *Introduction to Linear Algebra* by Strang. Let $A^H$ be the transpose conjugate of $A$, and suppose $A$ is normal, i.e. $AA^H = A^H A$.

Examine an eigenpair $Ax = \lambda x$. Multiply by $A^H$ and we have $A^H Ax = AA^H x = \lambda A^H x$. Assume only one $x$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ (see note at end), so here we know that $A^H x$ is a multiple of $x$, i.e. $A^H x = c x$. Multiply by $x^H$ and we have $c = \bar \lambda$, i.e. the conjugate of $\lambda$.

Now consider another eigenpair $A y = \mu y$ with $\mu \neq \lambda$. From the result in the previous paragraph, we have $y^H A = \mu y^H$. Now multiply by $x$ and we obtain $\mu y^H x = \lambda y^H x$, which leads to $y^H x = 0$.

Note: if there are multiple $x$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then choose $x$ to be the linear combination that is also an eigenvector of $A^H$. Such a choice is always be possible given that there's at least one eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$ (proof is left as an exercise for the reader).

Answer (score -1):

A normal matrix is unitarily similar to diagonal matrix.

$$A = UDU^{-1}$$ where $U$ is Unitary matrix.

Eigen decompositions tells that $U$ is a matrix composed of columns which are eigenvectors of $A$. And matrix $D$ is Diagonal matrix with eigenvalues on diagonal.

> *Property*: Columns of Unitary matrix are orthogonal.

So, columns of $U$ (which are eigenvectors of $A$) are orthogonal.