# Simple Problem on Orthogonality of Eigenvectors of Hermitian or Normal Matrices

Tags: matrices

I know how to prove:

Given an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with $\lambda$ and $\mu$ being distinct eigenvalues and $x$ and $y$ are their corresponding eigenvectors. Show that $y^{H}x=0$.

---

However, if I change $A$ to be a normal matrix, I would like to ask if we can get a similar result that $y^{*}x=0$? (I denote the $*$ to be conjugate transpose.)

Thank you your attention so much.

---

**Update for more.**

I do not know how to prove this statement:

If $A$ is not Hermitian and suppose $Ax=\lambda x$ and $y^{H}A=\mu y^{H}$. Show that $y^{H}x \neq 0$. (Algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda =1$.)

---

My Trial:
Suppose $y^{H}x=0$.

Then, from $y^{H}A=\mu y^{H}$, we have $y^{H}Ax=\mu y^{H}x \Rightarrow $ $\lambda y^{H}x=\mu y^{H}x=0.$

But I fail to derive contradiction:(

Comment: See, e.g., [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/778973/90996).

Comment: @Pavel Thank you for your links.

Answer (score 1):

About your update:

Let $\mu\neq 0$. Then $$y^Hx = \frac1\mu(\mu y^H x) = \frac1\mu y^HAx = \frac\lambda\mu y^Hx$$
meaning that if $\lambda \neq \mu$, $y^Hx=0$ must hold.

As for the main question, I first offer a hint:

**Hint:** First show that if $A$ is normal, then $Ax=\lambda x$ holds iff $A^*x\bar\lambda x$.

Comment: thx but why your second equality holds?

Comment: Because I replaced $\mu y^H$ with $y^H A$ which is true.

Comment: Thanks for your help...but the question asks me to prove $y^{H}x \neq 0$. Do I misunderstand your words or the question is wrong indeed?

Comment: $y^Hx\neq 0$ is false if $\lambda \neq \mu$ and $\mu\neq 0$, as I have shown.

Comment: Thank you for your comment very much. Could you please relieve my worry about the question that if $A$ is normal, can we claim that $y^{H}x=0$ as well?