# Orthogonality of Eigenvectors corresponding to different type of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I've learnt the amazing eigensystem of real symmetric matrices has the 2 following properties:

1. The eigenvalues are real number.
2. The eigenvectors could be chosen to be orthogonal when we diagonalize it.

As I keep learning through 18.06 to [Unit 3 Exam Review](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/positive-definite-matrices-and-applications/exam-3-review/), prof. Strang noted that:

> A matrix has orthogonal eigenvectors exactly when $AA^T$ = $A^TA$; i.e. when A commutes with its transpose. This is true of symmetric, skew symmetric and orthogonal matrices.

Does anybody know how can I prove the theorem above starting from $AA^T$ = $A^TA$? Is there any useful proposition I can use?

It's my first time to ask question on this forum. Any suggestion or hint would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is essentially the content of the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Finite-dimensional_case); you can find a proof in many linear algebra texts (e.g. Friedberg Insel Spense and Hoffman Kunze; not sure about Strang).  In my [question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/778946/81360), you can find more direct proofs for the specific point of orthogonality of eigenvectors.

Comment: @Ben, Thanks for the hint of spectral theorem. I found this [document](http://www.math.umd.edu/~hking/Hermitian.pdf) provided by UMD. It provides an intuitive proof of Spectral theorem based on Schur decomposition and a brief justification of why normal matrices could be diagonalized with an unitary matrix. And my question is just a special case of normal matrices.

Comment: Glad you found something that works for you! Using the Schur decomposition leads to a very quick approach (and is presented also in Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis* and Friedberg Insel Spense), but it never felt quite as intuitive to me

Comment: It's perhaps more intuitive to separate the two factors at play: (1) $AB=BA$ for some $B$, (2) $B=A^T$. The first factor guarantees that $A$ and $B$ share a common eigenvector $x$ over $\mathbb C$. The second factor guarantees that $Y=(\operatorname{span}\{x\})^\perp$ is an invariant subspace of $A$ and $A^T$. Now, by considering the restrictions of $A$ and $A^T$ on $Y$ and by proceeding recursively, we can obtain a common orthogonal eigenbasis of $A$ and $A^T$.

Comment: @user1551 That's an interesting perspective!

Comment: Is it easier to deal this problem with the concepts of spaces and linear mapping? But I don't understand the construction of sharing a common eigenvector $x$ based on the first factor. Is that first factor a eigenvalue? It seems that there are still a large subspace that I haven't explored in Linear Algebra!!

Comment: "The first factor" in my comment refers to the fact that $AB=BA$ for some matrix $B$. Matrices are sometimes useful and sometimes not. In the present case it's easier to consider linear operators rather than matrices. Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two commuting linear operators over an algebraically closed field (e.g. $\mathbb C$). Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ and $W=\{w: Aw=\lambda w\}$ be the corresponding eigenspace. For any $w\in W$, we have $A(Bw)=BAw=B(\lambda w)=\lambda Bw$. Hence $Bw\in W$. It follows that $BW\subseteq W$, i.e. $W$ is an invariant subspace of $B$...

Comment: ...Now consider the restriction of $B$ on $W$. It is a linear operator on $W$ over an algebraically closed field. Therefore $B$ has an eigenvector $x$ in $W$. However, by definition, every vector in $W$ is an eigenvector of $A$. Hence $x$ is a common eigenvector of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: With the first factor, we  know that $A$ and $B$ share a common eigenvector $x$.

And with the second factor ($B=A^T$):
There exist an $Y=(span\{x\})^\perp$, and we could choose any vector $y \in Y$ and show that $Y$ is an invariant subspace of $A$ and $A^T$ with the following statements:
(1) Case of $A$: $(Ay)^Tx = y^TA^Tx = y^T \lambda x = \lambda y^T x = 0$
(2) Case of $A^T$: $(A^Ty)^Tx = y^TAx = y^T \lambda x = \lambda y^T x = 0$
Since $A$ and $A^T$ share the common eigenvector $x$, the results of $Ay$ and $A^ty$ are guaranteed to be perpendicular to any vector $y \in Y$....

Comment: ...Therefore, by the retrieving the shared eigenvector $x_i$ in $Y_{i-1}$  and produce $Y_i$ recursively, we would be able to obtain a common orthogonal eigenbasis for $A$ and $A^T$. Does my reconstruction meet what you mean? Or is there any flaw?