# How to show symmetric matrices are orthogonally diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

> We say that a matrix $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is symmetric if $A^T=A$, and that $U\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is orthogonal if $U^TU=UU^T=I$.  Show the following.
>
> (a) Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and let $g$ be an inner product on $V$.  Let $E$ and $B$ be two orthonormal bases on $V$.  Show that the change of basis matrix $[I]^E_B$ is orthogonal.
>
> (b) Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be symmetric. Show that there is an orthogonal matrix $U\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such taht $U^TAU$ is diagonal.

I've done part (a), but I cannot do part (b).

I had a plan to somehow use the spectral theorem, but I cannot do it.

Any help!

Comment: What you are trying to do is show that symmetric matrices are orthogonally diagonalizable.

Comment: @RichardP Yes but I somehow have to construct an orthogonal matrix which has eigenvectors as it's columns, I'm not sure how

Comment: Recall that if A is a $n\times n$ symmetric matrix, then there exists a set of n orthonormal eigenvectors for A.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82467/eigenvectors-of-real-symmetric-matrices-are-orthogonal has useful information on this question

Comment: @RichardP Where does this follow from?

Comment: Bastardizing the spectral theorem a little bit.

Comment: You should give a citation for the quoted text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are allowed to use the spectral theorem, the proof of (v) is easy:

The spectral theorem says that for a real symmetric matrix $A$ there is an orthonormal set of eigenvectors $\{ \bf{e}_i\}$ such that
$$
\begin{array}{c}
A{\bf e}_i = \lambda_i {\bf e}_i \\
{\bf e}_i^T A = \lambda_i {\bf e}_i^T \\
\left< {\bf e}_i^T , {\bf e}_j \right> = \delta_{ij}
\end{array}
$$
Now consider $U$ such that
$$
U_{ij} = [{\bf e}_i]_j
$$
Then $AU$ is a square matrix with column $i$ equal to ${\bf e}_i$ for each $i$.  From which:
$$
[U^T(AU)]_{ki} = \lambda_i \left< {\bf e}_k^T , {\bf e}_i \right> = \lambda_i \delta_{ki}
$$
so $U^TAU = U^T(AU)$ is a diagonal matrix with elements $\lambda_i$.

Comment: I presume it is $\lambda_i\cdot \langle e_k^T, e_i\rangle$, right?

Comment: Good catch; no dot though. I just had accidentally left a < sign from before I changed to actual angle brackets.