# Condition on unitary operator for real eigenstates of Hamiltonian

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quantum-mechanics, unitary-matrices, hermitian-matrices

I'm working with the discrete-time quantum walk in which the evolution is described by the unitary operator -

$$U = S(I\otimes C)$$
where $C$ is the coin operator (acts on spin degree of freedom of particle) described by $SU(2)$ rotation, and $S$ is shift operator given by

$$S = \sum_x \left[ |x+1\rangle \langle x|\otimes |\uparrow\rangle \langle \uparrow | +|x-1\rangle \langle x|\otimes |\downarrow\rangle \langle \downarrow |  \right]$$
Although, this description may not be necessary for what it follows. The Hamiltonian associated with this unitary given by

$$U = \exp(-iH) \rightarrow H =i \log(U)$$

I'm looking for a condition that I can put on $U$ so that $H$ has real eigenvectors or eigenstates. I think if $H$ is a real hermitian matrix, then, of course, it should have real eigenstates. But I'm not sure what condition to impose on $U$ (or choice of $C$).

Answer (score 0):

*Short answer:* If you for some reason know that no eigenvalues of $H$ differ by a (non-zero) multiple of $2\pi$, then the condition on $U\in U(n)$ you are looking for is that it satisfies $\overline{U}U={\bf1}$;
here $\overline{U}$ denotes the entrywise complex conjugate of $U$.

*Long answer:* The key observation here is:

> A Hermitian matrix $H$ has real eigenvectors if and only if $H$ is symmetric (i.e. $H=H^T$).

This is due to the fact that [they can be diagonalized via an orthogonal matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1050582/how-to-show-symmetric-matrices-are-orthogonally-diagonalizable).
Then, defining $U:=\exp(-iH)$ one finds that:

> If a Hermitian matrix $H$ is symmetric, then $\overline{U}U={\bf1}$ which is equivalent to $U^{-1}=\overline{U}$.

*Proof.*
As $H$ is Hermitian and symmetric we know $\overline{H}=(H^*)^T=H^T=H$. Therefore
$$
U^{-1}=\exp(iH)=\exp(i\overline{H})=\overline{\exp(-iH)}=\overline{U}\,.\tag*{$\square$}
$$

However, the converse need not hold and it's for the same reason that the matrix logarithm is not as straightforward.
For this consider the Hamiltonian
$$
H=\begin{pmatrix}
\pi&i\pi\\-i\pi&\pi
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which is obviously not symmetric, but because $H$ has eigenvalues $0$ and $2\pi$, $U=e^{-iH}$ has eigenvalues $1,e^{-2\pi i}=1,1$ so $U={\bf1}$. In other words we found a non-symmetric Hamiltonian for which $\overline{U}U={\bf1}$ (trivially).

Yet, distinct eigenvalues differing by multiples of $2\pi$ is the only problem that can occur:

> Let $H$ be a Hermitian matrix such that for all eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ of $H$ there exists no $n\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ such that $\lambda_1=\lambda_2+2\pi n$.
> Then $H$ is symmetric if and only if $\overline{U}U={\bf1}$ (equivalently: $U^{-1}=\overline{U}$).

*Proof.*
We already proved "$\Rightarrow$" above. For "$\Leftarrow$": $U^{-1}=\overline{U}$ as before implies $\exp(iH)=\exp(i\overline{H})$.
Now because $H$ is Hermitian we can diagonalize: $H=VDV^*$ with $V$ unitary and $D$ diagonal and real. This implies $\overline{H}=\overline{V^*}\overline{D}\overline{V}=V^TD\overline{V}$ and thus $e^{iH}=Ve^{iD}V^*=V^Te^{iD}\overline{V}=e^{i\overline{H}}$.
Rearranging things one arrives at $\overline{V}Ve^{iD}=e^{iD}\overline{V}V$, i.e. $[\overline{V}V,e^{iD}]=\overline{V}Ve^{iD}-e^{iD}\overline{V}V=0$ ("$\overline{V}V$ commutes with $e^{iD}$").
The "$2\pi$-condition" we imposed on $H$ now guarantees that $e^{iD}$ and $D$ have the same commutant as different eigenvalues of $H$ are mapped to different eigenvalues under $e^{i\bullet}$; in particular this lets us conclude that $e^{iD}$ and $D$ have the same commutant, that is, $[\overline{V}V,e^{iD}]=0$ is equivalent to $[\overline{V}V,D]=0$. *[Note that this is precisely where our argument would break for the above example of $H$ as there, $e^{iD}={\bf1}$ commutes with everything, but $D$ doesn't].*
But with this we are done:
$$
H^T=V^TD\overline{V}=V^TD\overline{V}VV^*=V^T\overline{V}VDV^*=\overline{VV^*}VDV^*=VDV^*=H\,.\tag*{$\square$}
$$

Comment: I didn't follow the argument that $-iH$ is a skew-symmetric matrix if $H$ is a symmetric matrix. I think -- $-iH$ would also be a symmetric matrix and not a skew-symmetric matrix.

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake there; thanks for pointing it out! It turns out that the condition was not $U^TU={\bf1}$ but $\overline{U}U={\bf1}$ (so conjugate instead of transpose), and one needs a condition on the spectrum of $H$ for this to be equivalent to real eigenvectors of $H$.

Comment: By the way @YoungKindaichi should your unitary read $U=S(I\otimes C)$ (rather than $U=S(C\otimes I)$) given that $S$ as you wrote it acts on "location $\otimes$ spin degree-of-freedom", meaning $C$ should be part of the second tensor factor, as well?

Comment: Yes! It should be $S(I\otimes C)$. I have edited. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Thanks! I have worked out the conditions to impose on the coin operator to satisfy. It's $C_\uparrow^2 = C_\downarrow^2 = 0$ and $C_\uparrow C_\downarrow + C_\downarrow C_\uparrow = I$, where $C_\uparrow  = C|\uparrow \rangle \langle \uparrow |$ and $C_\downarrow = C|\downarrow \rangle \langle \downarrow |$.