# If $\ A$ is a *real symmetric matrix of order n* then $\ A$ has *n* linearly independent eigenvectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

How do you prove the question above? This is a sub-part of a proof that *real symmetric matrices of order n* is diagonalizable.

Comment: See the answer to your previous question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317936/why-does-a-symmetric-matrix-have-a-complete-set-of-eigenvectors-and-eigenvalues

Answer (score 0):

[Eigenvectors of real symmetric matrices are orthogonal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82467/eigenvectors-of-real-symmetric-matrices-are-orthogonal)

Look at this one. It has your answer. Try looking around the forum to see if the question you have asked has already been dealt with, in some other post.