# Eigenvectors of real symmetric matrices are orthogonal (more discussion)

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

This is an old question, and the proof is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82467/eigenvectors-of-real-symmetric-matrices-are-orthogonal)

The proof assumed different eigenvalues with different eigenvectors.

My question is how about the repeated root? How to guarantee there will not be only one independent eigenvector such that all eigenvectors can form the orthogonal basis of the vector space?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  However, on the matter of eigenvalues not being distinct, eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue are certainly not always orthogonal.  If you have two orthogonal eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue, then every linear combination of them is another eigenvector with that same eigenvalue, and is not generally orthogonal to the two you started with. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael Hardy  My question is just to check if geometric multiplicity < algebraic multiplicity in the case of symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that for a symmetric matrix $A$ there exists a Jordan block for an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of size more than one, hence there exists at least two  linear independent *generalized* eigenvectors, i.e. $By=x$ and $Bx=0$ where $B=A-\lambda I$. Estimate $x^TBy$. On one hand it is $0^Ty=0$, on other hand, it is $x^Tx=\|x\|^2$. It gives $x=0$ which is a contradiction with the vectors being linear independent. Hence all chains of generalized eigenvectors are of length one, i.e. they are eigenvectors for $A$.

**Addendum:** As @Ian correctly noticed, one has to add to the proof that the basis of the corresponding eigen-subspace for $\lambda$ can be chosen orthogonal.

Comment: I honestly don't see what this has to do with the question. It seems to be a (correct) proof that a symmetric matrix is diagonalizable, but to say nothing about orthogonality.

Comment: @ian Sorry, I missed to mention that one can do orthogonalization within a corresponding eigen-subspace.

Answer (score 8):

There are really three things going on here:

1. Eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are all orthogonal.
2. A symmetric matrix is diagonalizable whether it has distinct eigenvalues or not. @A.G. proved this just fine already.
3. Given a subspace whose dimension is greater than $1$, one can choose a basis of the subspace consisting of orthogonal elements. This is usually proven constructively by applying Gram-Schmidt.

Thus, it is *not* the case that *all* pairs of non-parallel eigenvectors of every symmetric matrix are orthogonal to each other. Rather, one can choose an orthogonal basis such that the matrix is diagonal in that basis. Nonetheless, for a symmetric matrix with a repeated eigenvalue, one can also choose a *non-orthogonal* basis such that the matrix is diagonal in that basis.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach to the proof (not using the inner-product method on the question you reference) is to use Schur's Theorem.

**Schur's Theorem:** Every square matrix $A$ has a factorization of the form $A=QTQ^{\ast}$ where $Q$ is a unitary matrix and $T$ is upper triangular.

Then, if $A$ is symmetric, $T$ must also be symmetric (and hence diagonal).  The columns of $Q$ are the eigenvectors of $A$ (easy to check), $T$ contains the eigenvalues (easy to check), and since $Q$ is unitary, all the columns are orthonormal.

Comment: If you want a reference, I have on my desk: "Numerical Linear Algebra" by Trefethen and Bau (published by SIAM).  Lecture 24 covers eigenvalues problems and has this result.