# Is a set of orthonormal eigenvectors directly an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

From a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix one can get a set of orthonormal eigenvectors.

Is a set of orthonormal eigenvectors directly an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$)?

Yes?

Comment: see: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/82471

Answer (score 2):

Any set of orthogonal nonzero vectors is linearly independent. If their number is equal to the dimension of the space then they also engender it.