# Scalar product of two vectors when only given equations

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

> Let $A$ be a symmetrical $2x2$ matrix. Given the equations
>
> $$A*v_1=4*v_1$$
>
> $$A*v_2=-v_2$$
>
> Determine the scalar product $v_1*v_2$

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be seen that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are two Eigenvectors corresponding to two different Eigenvalues ($4$ and $-1$) of $A$. Eigenvectors of real symmetric matrices are orthogonal.

Therefore $<v_1,v_2>=0$.

For generalized proof see:
[Eigenvectors of real symmetric matrices are orthogonal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82467/eigenvectors-of-real-symmetric-matrices-are-orthogonal)