# Decomposition of symmetric matrix and inner product of eigen vector

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was studying matrices and I came to know the following two results:

1. Real symmetric matrices, $A = P D P^{-1} = P D P^T$ where $D$ is diagonal
2. For any real matrix $A$ and any vectors $x$ and $y$, $\langle A\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\rangle = \langle\mathbf{x},A^T\mathbf{y}\rangle.$

Please explain me the meaning of second and proof of the first. In general I want to understand the meaning of answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82467/eigenvectors-of-real-symmetric-matrices-are-orthogonal/82471#82471).

Comment: What do you mean by meaning of the second? It means what it's written: inner product of $Ax$ and $y$ is exactly inner product of $x$ and $A^T y$.

Comment: By its meaning I meant, what does the inner product of $Ax$ and $y$ signify ? Also its proof.

Comment: I don't know how to interpret it in some significant way. It's just the definition of the standard inner product on $\Bbb R^n$: $(Ax) \cdot y = (Ax)^T y = x^T A^T y = x \cdot (A^T y)$.

Comment: What does $\langle A\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\rangle$ signifies ?