# Show that the eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues of the symmetric matrix are orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Just a quick question:

For the matrix 
  $$
  \begin{pmatrix}
   2 & 2 \\
   2 & 2\\
  \end{pmatrix} 
$$
Show that the eigenvectors of the matrix are orthogonal.

I can tell that the eigenvectors are $(-0.5, 1)$ and $(2, 1)$. I'm just not sure how to show they are orthogonal.

Comment: Are you sure about those eigenvectors? Multiplying $(2,1)^T$ by the matrix does *not* result in a scalar multiple of $(2,1)^T$. The image of the matrix is the span of $(1,1)^T$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eigenvectors of real symmetric matrices are orthogonal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82467/eigenvectors-of-real-symmetric-matrices-are-orthogonal)

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Take the dot product of the two eigenvectors and see!

Comment: Actually, the eigenvectors given by the OP are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

That result holds in general.

If $u$ and $v$ are eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues $\lambda_u$ and $\lambda_v$ of a symmetric matrix $A$ ($A=A^T$) then we can use the relation that is always true:

$$(Au)\cdot v=u\cdot (A^Tv)$$

Using that $A=A^T$ we have

$$\lambda_u(u\cdot v)=\lambda_v(u\cdot v)\to(\lambda_u-\lambda_y)(u\cdot v)=0$$

but $\lambda_u\ne \lambda_v$ so

$$u\cdot v=0$$

Comment: Does this results holds only in real matrices?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as pointed out by @amd, you've made a mistake with the eigenvectors. The eigenvalues are:
$$(2-\lambda)^2-4=-4\lambda+\lambda^2=\lambda(\lambda-4)=0$$
Which implies that: $\lambda_1=0$ and $\lambda_2=4$.
Therefore, the eigenvectors are:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}=0\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} \implies x_1=-x_2 \implies v_1=\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}=4\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} \implies x_1=x_2 \implies v_2=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

---

Let's now show that the eigenvectors of the matrix are orthogonal. Let's start with the formula for the angle $\theta$ between two vectors $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}$:
$$\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{v}=\|\mathbf{u}\|\|\mathbf{v}\|\cos{\theta}$$
Now, for orthogonal vectors: $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$. This is because two Euclidean vectors are called orthogonal if they are perpendicular. Therefore:
$$\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{v}=0$$
Thus, you must show that the dot product of your two eigenvectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ is equal to zero.