# Find a matrix P that orthogonally diagonalizes A

Tags: linear-algebra

For the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}
   2 & 2 \\
   2 & 2 \\
  \end{pmatrix}$$

Find a matrix that orthogonally diagonalizes A. Find a matrix such that $P^t$$AP$ is diagonal.

Comment: The columns of $P$ are the normalised eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: If you’d gotten the correct eigenvectors of this matrix in [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2207310/265466), you’d be done.

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvectors are easily seen to be $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$, which gives
$$ P = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}, $$
and
$$ P^{T} \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix} P = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Find the eigenvectors and construct a matrix P with colums of P the eigenvectors. This P will give you what you want.

Comment: No, this won't always work. We need $P$ to be orthogonal. Just putting the eigenvectors together is not enough.