# If $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ is symmetric, why can we find a pair of orthonormal eigenvectors $q_1=(x_1,-y_1)^T$, and $q_2=(y_1,x_1)^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am okay with the fact that we can find a pair of orthonormal eigenvectors, but **how do we know that we can find some of the form $q_1=(x_1,-y_1)^T$, and $q_2=(y_1,x_1)^T$?**

NOTE: I'm not sure if we need $A$ to be real matrix here, but if so feel free to assume it.

Edit:In response to being possible duplicate... that question is about diagonalization and why eigenvectors of a real symmetric matrix are orthogonal. **my question here is about why there are orthogonal eigenvectors of a certain form.**

> That is, we know that there are orthogonal eigenvectors. But **how come the orthogonal vectors** $q_1=(x_1,-y_1)^T$, and $q_2=(y_1,x_1)^T$ **are eigenvectors** (as opposed to just being orthogonal vectors)?

Comment: Shouldn't the second component in $q_2$ be $x_1$?

Comment: @AnuragA yes, it was a typo. I will fix it now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eigenvectors of real symmetric matrices are orthogonal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82467/eigenvectors-of-real-symmetric-matrices-are-orthogonal)

Comment: The "certain form" you ask about is just a restatement of what it means to have a pair of othogonal vectors in $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick *any* eigenvector $\mathbf v=(y_1,x_1)$ of $A$. What do the vectors $(x,y)$ that are orthogonal to it look like? Well, we must have $(y_1,x_1)\cdot(x,y)=y_1x+x_1y=0$. This is the equation of a line through the origin with direction vector $(x_1,-y_1)$, i.e., every vector orthogonal to $\mathbf v$ is a scalar multiple of $(x_1,-y_1)$. You agree that $A$ has orthogonal eigenvectors, which means that $(x_1,-y_1)$ in particular is itself an eigenvector of $A$. If in addition $\mathbf v$ is a unit vector (which we can always arrange by normalizing any eigenvector of $A$), then it should be clear that $(x_1,-y_1)$ is also a unit vector.

Comment: "You agree that $A$ has orthogonal eigenvectors, which means that $(x1,−y1)$ in particular is itself an eigenvector of $A$". This is because the following? Say we have two orthogonal eigenvectors for $A$, one of which is $\textbf{v}$ Then we know that the other eigenvector, call it $\textbf{w}$ is a scalar multiple of $(x_1,-y_1)$, as you showed. So then $\textbf{w}=\alpha (x_1,-y_1)$ for some $\alpha$. But scalar multiples of eigenvectors are also eigenvectors (since we can multiply the corresponding eigenvector by the same scalar). Thus $(x_1,-y_1)$ is also an eigenvector of $A$.

Comment: @user106860 Looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Let $( q_1, q_2 )$ be **any orthonormal basis of eigenvectors** of our real matrix $A$ (the existence of such a basis follows from the [Spectral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem)). Let us denote the entries of $q_1$ and $q_2$ by $q_1 = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}$ and $q_2 = \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ x_1 \end{pmatrix}$ where $y_1, x_1$ are known fixed entries, like in your notation.

Now we would like to **show** that we can choose $q_1$ such that $a = x_1$ and $b = -y_1$.

- First of all we note that the set
  $$
   U = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \: : \: \langle x, q_2 \rangle = 0 \}
  $$
  is a **one-dimensional subspace** of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is **generated** by $q_1$
  (this follows from the fact that $(q_1,q_2)$ constitutes an orthonormal basis, so the scalar product of $q_1$ and $q_2$ is $0$, i.e. $q_1 \in U$).
- The basis $(q_1, q_2)$ being orthonormal also means that the **norms** of $q_1$ and $q_2$ are $1$, i.e.
  $$
  1 = \langle q_1, q_1 \rangle = \langle \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} \rangle = a^2 + b^2
  $$
  and 
  $$
  1 = \langle q_2, q_2 \rangle = \langle \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} \rangle = y_1^2 + x_1^2.
  $$
- We **claim** now that there are **only two vectors** in $U$ that have norm $1$, namely $q_1$ and $-q_1$:

  Indeed, let $u$ be any vector in $U$. Because $U$ is generated by $q_1$ there exists a scalar $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $u = \lambda q_1 = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda a \\ \lambda b \end{pmatrix}$. Therefore, we get $\langle u , u \rangle = \lambda^2 (a^2 + b^2) = \lambda^2 $ and the scalar product is $1$ if and only if $\lambda \in \{1,-1\}$, i.e. $u = q_1$ or $ u = -q_1$.
- We observe that the vector $\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ -y_1 \end{pmatrix} $ has **norm** $1$, as
  $$ \langle \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ -y_1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ -y_1 \end{pmatrix} \rangle = x_1^2 + y_1^2 = 1 $$
  as we can see from the second bullet.
- Furthermore, the same vector **lies in** $U$ because
  $$ \langle \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ -y_1 \end{pmatrix} , q_2 \rangle = \langle \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ -y_1 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ x_1 \end{pmatrix} \rangle = x_1 y_1 - y_1 x_1 = 0.
  $$
- But we already know from the third bullet that $q_1$ and $-q_1$ are the only two vectors in $U$ with norm $1$. That means that **either $q_1$ or $-q_1$ equals $\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ -y_1 \end{pmatrix}$**.
- **Case 1**: If $q_1$ is equal $\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ -y_1 \end{pmatrix}$, then we are done.
- **Case 2**: If $q_1$ is not $\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ -y_1 \end{pmatrix}$, then $-q_1$ must be $\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ -y_1 \end{pmatrix}$. But then this is also okay, because we can choose $-q_1$ instead of $q_1$, as $(-q_1,q_2)$ is also an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors of $A$.