# How to prove symmetric matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable?

Tags: orthogonality

I learned below theorem and there is a proof that orthogonally diagonalizable matrix is symmetric, but there is no proof that symmetric matrix are orthogonally diagonalizable.

> Theorem 2. An $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is orthogonally diagonalizable if
>   and only if $A$ is a symmetric matrix.

I searched proof in this website and found [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/82471/590853), but I cannot understand why $\langle Ax,y \rangle = \langle x, A^Ty \rangle$.

How can I prove?

Comment: I think you are in search of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing the inner product $\langle v, w \rangle$ as $v^\top w$, we have
$$\langle Ax, y\rangle  = (Ax)^\top y = x^\top A^\top y = \langle x, A^\top y\rangle.$$

Comment: Then, inner product is thought as vector space in $\Bbb{R}^n$ not general vector space?

Comment: You are multiplying the vectors by an $n \times n$ matrix $A$, so yes.

Comment: Thank you, angryavian