# Inequality manipulation for a vector norm

Tags: inequality, control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

How can I manipulate the following inequality to reach from
$$\dot{V}\leq -4x_1^2 +4x_1x_2 -2x_2^2 $$
to
$$\dot{V}\leq -(3-\sqrt{5}) \|x\|^2 $$
where $x=[x_1 \;x_2]^T$ is a 2D vector and $\|x\|$ is the euclidean norm of $x?$ It is related to Lyapunov stability and I need to get something of the following form:
$$\dot{V} \leq -k\|x\|^2,$$
where $k$ is some positive constant.

Comment: By norm, are you referring to the Euclidean Norm defined by $||x||=\sqrt{x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}}$?

Comment: Yes, the Euclidean Norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_1=a$ and $x_2=b$.

Thus, $$-4a^2+4ab-2b^2\leq-(3-\sqrt5)(a^2+b^2)$$ it's
$$(1+\sqrt5)a^2-4ab+(\sqrt5-1)b^2\geq0$$ or
$$(1+\sqrt5)^2-4(1+\sqrt5)ab+4b^2\geq0$$ or
$$((1+\sqrt5)a-2b)^2\geq0.$$
We can get a value $-3+\sqrt5$ by the following way.

Let $$-4a^2+4ab-2b^2\leq k(a^2+b^2)$$ is true for all reals $a$ and $b$.

Thus, $$(4+k)a^2-4ab+(2+k)b^2\geq0,$$ for which we need $4+k>0$ and $$4-(4+k)(2+k)\leq0$$ or
$$k^2+6k+4\geq0,$$ which since $k>-4$ (we see that even $k>-2$), gives
$$k\geq-3+\sqrt5.$$
Id est, the minimal value of $k$ for which our inequality holds for all variables it's $k=-3+\sqrt5.$

Why we took a minimal value? Because we want that the equality will occur.

Comment: This answer assumes that the bound is known. In control theory and Lyapunov Stability exercises this is not given. So it is not about demonstrating the validity but rather about the way how such a bound is found.

Comment: @MrYouMath I added something. See now.

Comment: Amazing addition! Quick and effective!

Answer (score 0):

Your $\dot{V}$ can also be expressed as the following quadratic expression in $x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \;x_2\end{bmatrix}^\top$, namely

$$
\dot{V} = x^\top P\,x,
$$

with

$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}-4 & 2 \\ 2 & -2\end{bmatrix}.
$$

It can be shown that $P$ has the eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = -3 + \sqrt{5}$ and $\lambda_2 = -3 - \sqrt{5}$. Now when assuming that $x$ is real and by using that [symmetric matrices have an orthogonal basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82467/eigenvectors-of-real-symmetric-matrices-are-orthogonal) then $x$ can also be written as

$$
x = \alpha_1\,v_1 + \alpha_2\,v_2,
$$

with $v_1,v_2$ the normalized eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ respectively and $\alpha_1,\alpha_2 \in\,\mathbb{R}$. So $\dot{V}$ can also be written as

\begin{align}
\dot{V} &= (\alpha_1\,v_1 + \alpha_2\,v_2)^\top P\,(\alpha_1\,v_1 + \alpha_2\,v_2) \\
&= (\alpha_1\,v_1 + \alpha_2\,v_2)^\top (\alpha_1\,\lambda_1\,v_1 + \alpha_2\,\lambda_2\,v_2) \\
&= \alpha_1^2\,\lambda_1 + \alpha_2^2\,\lambda_2
\end{align}

When looking for bounds of $\dot{V}$ in terms of some scalar times $\|x\|^2$ we might as well set $\|x\|^2$ to one. Since we have an [orthonormal basis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthonormalBasis.html) it holds that $\|x\|^2 = \alpha_1^2 + \alpha_2^2$. From this it can be observed that $\dot{V}$ is maximized when $\alpha_1^2 = 1$ and $\alpha_0^2 = 0$, since $\lambda_1$ is the largest eigenvalue of $P$. Similarly  $\dot{V}$ is minimized when $\alpha_1^2 = 0$ and $\alpha_0^2 = 1$, since $\lambda_2$ is the largest eigenvalue of $P$.

Answer (score 0):

I will add an alternative method. Introduce polar cooridnates $x_1=r\cos \alpha$ and $x_2 = r\sin \alpha$ (note that $x_1^2+x_2^2=||\boldsymbol{x}||^2 = r^2$) to obtain

$$\dot{V} \leq -4r^2\cos^2\alpha-2r^2\sin^2\alpha+4r^2\sin \alpha\cos\alpha$$
$$\implies \dot{V}\leq -r^2\left[2\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha-2\sin \alpha \cos\alpha \right]$$

Use $\cos^2 \alpha + \sin^2 \alpha = 1$ and $2\sin \alpha \cos\alpha=\sin 2\alpha$
$$\implies \dot{V}\leq r^2\left[\sin 2\alpha-\cos^2\alpha-1\right]$$

We want to find extrema of the expression in the bracket, hence we introduce $f(\alpha)=\sin 2\alpha -\cos^2 \alpha -1 \implies f'(\alpha)=2\cos2\alpha + 2\cos\alpha\left[-\sin \alpha \right]$ set this expression equal to $0$ and try to solve the resulting equation. Check which of the values results in the highest $f(\alpha)$ it should result in your upper bound.

Alternatively, you can apply $\cos^2 \alpha = \dfrac{1+\cos 2\alpha}{2}$ to obtain

$$f(\alpha) =\dfrac{2\sin 2\alpha -\cos 2\alpha -3}{2}.$$

In the last step, we use the following observation

$$C\sin(x+y) = C\sin x\cos y +  C\cos x \sin y=A\sin x + B \cos x$$

By comparing these we obtain
$$A=C\cos y$$
$$B=C\sin y$$
$$\implies C = \sqrt{A^2+B^2} \qquad \text{only this is important}$$
$$\implies \tan y = \dfrac{B}{A} \qquad \text{not necessary}$$

For

$$f(\alpha) =\dfrac{2\sin 2\alpha -\cos 2\alpha -3}{2}=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}\sin (2\alpha + y) -3}{2}$$

$$\implies \dfrac{-\sqrt{5}-3}{2} \leq f(\alpha) \leq \dfrac{+\sqrt{5}-3}{2}.$$

> This method is sometimes fast because it is often possible to get a
>   crude estimate for $f(\alpha)$ here $f(\alpha)\leq 1 - 0 -1 =0$ for
>   the case that the sine is $1$ and the cosine is $0$ (unrealistic but
>   crude enoght to get $\dot{V}\leq 0$.