# Must generalized eigenvectors of distinct eigenvalues be orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

Let $v_1, v_2$ be generalized eigenvectors of ranks $l_1, l_2 > 0$, which respectively belong to eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$ of the linear operator $A$:

$(A - \lambda_i I)^{l_i} v_i = 0$ and $(A - \lambda_i I)^{l_i - 1} v_i \neq 0$

The standard proof for usual eigenvectors ([e.g., here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/82471/53919)) assumes that $A$ is symmetric.

**Question**:
Must $v_1$ and $v_2$ be orthogonal? For an arbitrary linear operator $A$? If not, I'd be glad to a counter-example. What conditions on $A$ guarantee that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are orthogonal?

NB Base field may be taken as reals or complex, don't mind.

Comment: A simple counterexample for $l_1 = l_2 = 1$:
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&2}.
$$
The eigenvectors $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ are not orthogonal.

Comment: Right. Thank you @BenGrossmann!