# If we find a restricted sub-space for a symmetric linear transform, will the restricted transform also be symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let's say we have a symmetric linear transform, $T$ over some space over $\Bbb R^n$ represented as a matrix $M$. Now, we find some sub-space, $W$ over $\Bbb R^k$ with $k<n$ such that applying $T$ on any vector, $u$ in $W$ results in a vector also in $W$. We now define a linear transform $T^*$ that is just $T$ when applied over the $W$ sub-space. Is it true that we can find a basis for $T^*$ such that the associated $k \times k$ matrix is also symmetric? In other words, $T^*$ is also a symmetric linear transform?

The reason I'm asking this is to complete a proof that symmetric matrices are diagonalizable: [Help verifying proof that symmetric matrices are diagonalizable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4357152/help-verifying-proof-that-symmetric-matrices-are-diagonalizable)

Answer (score 1):

First to get a small technical gripe out the way, it doesn't really make sense to talk about a linear transformation being symmetric without additional structure  (as opposed to talking about the matrix representing $T$ w.r.t a specific basis). This is because being symmetric isn't invariant under changes of basis, so by the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) we have that

There exists a basis $B$ such that $T$ is symmetric $\iff$ $T$ is diagonalisable

The situation changes if you impose an inner product on the space, as then you can talk about orthonormal vectors, and being symmetric **is** preserved under orthogonal changes of basis

---

So with this information the question becomes:

> Is a diagonalisable matrix still diagonalisable when restricted to an invariant subspace

Of which the answer is yes, as it then becomes a repeat of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62338/diagonalizable-transformation-restricted-to-an-invariant-subspace-is-diagonaliza)

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that the reason I want to prove this is to complete a proof for the very fact that symmetric matrices are diagonalizable (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4357152/help-verifying-proof-that-symmetric-matrices-are-diagonalizable). So invoking diagonalization becomes circular reasoning. Of course, no way you could have known this.