# Example of a non-diagonalizable matrix where the Eigen vectors corresponding to different Eigen values are orthogonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

In the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/833622/155881, a word of caution is raised around the possibility that a matrix could have the Eigen vectors corresponding to distinct Eigen values orthogonal to each other and yet non-diagonalizable because one of the Eigen values has multiple Eigen vectors, not all independent. It is proved that this isn't possible with symmetric matrices. But to drive home the point, is it possible with non-symmetric real matrices? If so, is there an example of such a matrix?

Comment: $\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 0&0&0}$.

Comment: You meant multiple eigenvalues, not eigenvectors.

Comment: Any matrix in Jordan canonical form has this property.